# how to measure text width in kineticjs?

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, text-width

Is there a method or workaround to return the text width of a string in a Text Shape, in KineticJs?

I would need it to position precisely the TextShape on the canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-metrics/) might help you. It demonstrates how to get the width of some text. There is also a link to another example showing how to do this for multi-line text, [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/).

Answer (score 9):

Kinetic.Text has getTextHeight() and getTextWidht() methods to do this for you.